# Add programs to start menu search without adding a tile

Tags: windows-8, start-menu, modern-ui

In Windows 7, I had many portable software programs like KeePass, PDF X-change, or Chrome application shortcuts that I used the portable version rather than full install. With these I was able to add a shortcut to my start menu that would hide in the All Programs list, but come up if I hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> and started typing.

I am trying to get the same functionality with Windows 8. I can pin programs to the start menu and have the tile for them, but for most of them I don't really need or want a tile. I just want Windows to know they are programs when I hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> and start typing. When I pin it to the start menu, it works. When I remove it, it doesn't.

Is there a way to add programs to the hidden part of the start menu. I've noticed that other programs I install have shortcuts that work without having a dedicated tile on the start screen. How can I get the same functionality with my own custom applications

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can open `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and add a shortcut there. It will appear both in the *All apps* list (on the Start screen, open the bottom menu and choose "All apps") and as a tile on the start screen itself. And it will also be available in app search. You then have to unpin the icon from the start screen by right-clicking on it and choosing *Unpin from Start* from the bottom menu.

For the local user's path, use `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` folder.

Comment: No go. I added a shortcut there and a tile immediately popped up on the start screen. I tried both the local user and the system-wide folders.

Comment: Right click, unpin from start. I'll modify the answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 5):

If you ever forget the path (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`) , you can always go to the `All apps` list, right-click on any app and then click on `Open File Location`. There you could add shortcut for any app you wish. It would be listed in `All apps` page, and show up when u search for it from Start Screen.

[image]