# Add a custom category to the "All Apps" part of Windows 8's Start Menu

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

How do I add a custom category to the "All Apps" part of the Windows 8 Start Menu? I've tried simply adding a folder to both `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` (not at the same time) a la [Add programs to start menu search without adding a tile](https://superuser.com/questions/493716/add-programs-to-start-menu-search-without-adding-a-tile). But those just add the folder's contents to the Desktop category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I just tried this myself.
I went to **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs** and created a folder called **Test**.

I found a random program's .exe, right-clicked it and clicked **Send to>Desktop(Create a Shortcut)**.

Then I moved that shortcut on the desktop inside **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Test**.

When I entered **Start Menu> All Apps (By Category)**, there was a Test category with the 'button' thingy linking to me .exe below it!

Note that to see the 'Test' category name, you must view All Apps **By Category** or **By Name.**

Refer to [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/172042/how-to-organize-the-all-apps-list-on-windows-8/) for more information.

I'm not sure why it didn't work for you... have you tried signing out and in again? Did you put a shortcut in the folder? Try following exactly the steps described in the link provided if it still doesn't work. :)